# log4net: Use AssemblyInfo.cs variables

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net, filepath

Is there a way to access the assembly variables from within the log4net config tag?  Currently we specify the log folder as follows:

```
  <!-- Setup Rolling Log File to log all information -->
  <appender name="DebugFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="${ProgramData}\\MyCompany\\MyProduct\\log\\Debug" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    ....
```

Is there a way to replace MyCompany and MyProduct with a variable which then reads the values from the project's AssemblyInfo.cs file?  Something similar to the '${ProgramData}'.

I have seen posts on how to setup a log4net variable that I could then reference later but I am hoping to reuse this config file among many projects without having to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use %property{propname} in your value attribute. Then in your start up set your property value:

```
GlobalContext.Properties["propname"] = "My Value";
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

You need to do this before configuring log4net (as shown above)

Just re-read your question and you may have already seen something like this. Not sure how else you expect it to magically work without some coding.

Comment: That is what I have now but was hoping for something like the ${ProgramData} environment variable that could resolve the Company and Product from the AssemblyInfo.cs file.  I already have to setup this info in AssemblyInfo.cs and was hoping to avoid another property that I would have to update each time I re-use the code.